# How I make result a list of booleans

Tags: haskell

I have this:

`getMask (/= 3) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

and result must be this:

`[True, True, False, True, True]`

i tried something like this

`getMask p xs = [x | (x,m) <- enumerate xs, if p x then True else False]`

but i get only numbers. I need list of booleans

Comment: if it works, just tweak it: `getMask p xs = [x | (x,m) <- enumerate xs, if p x then True else False] = [ if p x then True else False | (x,m) <- enumerate xs ]`. the `if p x then True else False` can be written shorter as just `p x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`:

```
> map (/= 3) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[True,True,False,True,True]
```

or a simple list comprehension:

```
getMask p xs = [p x | x <- xs]
```